# RSA Encryption - find the 'e' key

Tags: flutter, dart, math, encryption, rsa

I'm making an application that calculates RSA keys, and encrypts and decrypts messages. I was able to find the keys n and , and saw that a formula is needed so that finding the key 'e' works correctly.

> 1 >  > () and () ()

> any number between 1 and the totient function of n,
> where the divisors of 'e' do not belong to the divisors of .

I would like to know a practical way to verify this.

Comment: Your notation is unfamiliar and your formula does not make any sense. Either define the meaning of your notation or use more standard notation from e.g. [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

Answer (score 0):

To say that "the divisors of 'e' do not belong to the divisors of " is just to say that `gcd(e,phi(n)) == 1`, which is easy to verify with the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Since you need to use the extended Euclidean Algorithm anyway to find the decryption exponent `d` from `e`, the same computation which certifies `e` could also find `d`. There are `phi(phi(n))` candidate `e`, so in practice you don't have to search very long.

I hope that this is a learning exercise rather than something you plan to use for real security in a product. Writing an implementation of RSA is somewhat easy, but writing a *secure* implementation is surprisingly hard. There is a lot more than just the basic number theory that needs to be done right to make your implementation resistant to known attacks.

Comment: I'm studying something that goes a little out of my comfort zone, as I'm quite used to just app design, and as I've always liked encryption, I decided to use it to learn more about the 'raw' part of Dart.